# How to fix identifier must be declared in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm creating a procedure and then execute it in SQL plus. The procedure is correctly created / updated, as you can see from the following code.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure add_sal(i_empno number, addsal out number)
 2  is
 3  begin
 4  select sal+1000
 5  into addsal
 6  from emp
 7  where empno=i_empno;
 8  end;
 9  /

Procedure created.
```

When I try to execute the procedure I'm getting an error that I don't understand.

```
SQL> exec add_sal(i_empno,addsal);
BEGIN add_sal(i_empno,addsal); END;
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'I_EMPNO' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> SQL> exec add_sal(i_empno,addsal);

You need to pass the **values**, *not* the **parameter names** itself.

Also, `addsal` is an **OUT parameter**, you need to first **declare** it.

In **SQL*Plus**:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_sal(
  2      i_empno NUMBER,
  3      addsal OUT NUMBER)
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT sal+1000 INTO addsal FROM emp WHERE empno=i_empno;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> SHO ERR
No errors.
SQL>
SQL> variable addsal NUMBER
SQL>
SQL> EXEC add_sal(7369, :addsal);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> PRINT addsal

    ADDSAL
----------
      1800

SQL>
```

Alternatively, **independent of SQL*Plus**, you could execute it as an **anonymous block**:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     o_addsal NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     add_sal(7369, o_addsal);
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The output is : '||o_addsal);
  6  END;
  7  /
The output is : 1800

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `i_empno` in `exec` statement you must define it before:

```
VARIABLE i_empno NUMBER
VARIABLE addsal NUMBER
BEGIN
 :i_empno:=4;
END;
/
exec add_sal(:i_empno,:addsal);
```

Or you need to pass some value:

```
VARIABLE addsal NUMBER
exec add_sal(1,:addsal);
```

Comment: hello,  i have executed the procedure in sql plus and its working fine now.but when i am using the same procedure in informatica it thowing the below error.Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code Message
ERROR 5/10/2015 12:13:20 PM node01_Unni-PC TRANSF_1_1_1 CMN_1022 Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ADD_SAL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP

Oracle Fatal Error
Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteSP

Oracle Fatal Error]

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to pass variable back from Oracle execution to informatica.

Comment: can you please explain how to pass variable from oracle to informatica